# Laravel 5.2 FatalErrorException in casasController.php line 51

Tags: laravel, object, controller, namespaces

i need your help. i'm building a webApp in Laravel5.2. This is the probles i can't solve...**FatalErrorException in casasController.php line 51**; i really dont know what to do...the odject is correctly declared in namespace and its saved once validate!

**This is my controller:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Oggetto;
use App\Categoria;
use DB;
use Session;

class casasController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $oggetti = DB::table('casas')->get();
        $categoriasSelect = DB::table('categorias')->get();
        return view('pages.casa')->with('categoriasSelect', $categoriasSelect)->with('oggetti', $oggetti);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nome' => 'required',
            'categoria' => 'required',
            'descrizione' => 'required'
            ]);

        $oggetto = new Oggetto;
        $oggetto->nome = $request->nome;
        $oggetto->categoria = $request->categoria;
        $oggetto->descrizione = $request->descrizione;
        $status = $request->nome;

        $oggetto->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Il tuo oggetto per la casa è stato salvato con successo!');

        return view('pages.casa')->with('oggetto', $oggetto);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**These are my routes:**

```
Route::get('/', 'pagesController@index');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'luogo'), function(){
    Route::get('casa',['as' => 'opzione1', 'uses' => 'casasController@index']);
    Route::get('parco',['as' => 'opzione2', function(){
        return view('pages.parco');
    }]);
    Route::get('stazione',['as' => 'opzione3', function(){
        return view('pages.stazione');
    }]);
});
Route::post('nome', ['as' => 'nomeInput', 'uses' => 'pagesController@form']);
//Authentication Routes(login) -->built in
Route::get('auth/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin']);
Route::post('auth/login', ['as' => 'loginPost', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']);
Route::get('auth/logout', [ 'as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout']);

//Registration Routes(new users) -->built in
Route::get('auth/register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister']);
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Route::post('categoria', ['as' => 'categ', 'uses' => 'categoriasController@newCat']);
Route::resource('oggetto/{status?}', 'casasController', ['except' => ['show']]);
```

**This is my view:**

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')

    <h1 class="text-center">Benvenuto a Casa</h1>
    <h3 class="text-center"><a href="" id="link_formOggetto"> Aggiungi un oggetto</a></h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                @if(count($errors) > 0)
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{$error}}</div>
                    @endforeach
                @elseif(Session::has('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('success')}}</div>
                @endif
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Categoria</th>
                            <th>Descrizione</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Azioni</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($oggetti as $oggetto)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$oggetto->nome}}</td>

                            <td>{{$oggetto->categoria}}</td>

                            <td>{{$oggetto->descrizione}}</td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Editare</button></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Cancellare</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="formOggetto" style="display: none; margin-top: 25px">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <form action="{{action('casasController@store')}}" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="categoria">
                                        <option value="null">Scegli...</option>
                                        @foreach($categoriasSelect as $categoriaSelect)
                                            <option>{{$categoriaSelect->nome}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label>Aggiungi nuova categoria</label>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCateg">Aggiungi</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="descrizione">Descrizione</label>
                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="descrizione" name="descrizione" placeholder="Descrizione"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Salva">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
@stop
```

Comment: Doesn't the error say anything else? Can you enable debugging so the error will tell you more?

Comment: 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true) but this is what it tells as error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you don't have Oggetto model, so you need to create it first.

Also change this:

```
$oggetto = new Oggetto;
```

to this:

```
$oggetto = new Oggetto();
```

Comment: Well, line 51 is the this one and I don't see any errors in it. Are you sure you've posted right controller?

Comment: Ok, you've got error in `Controller.php`, update your answer with it's code please. DId you modify it?

Comment: i think so...the form and the route are both pointing to casasController (the form by action="action(casasController@store)")

Comment: yes i did, the error is: FatalErrorException in casasController.php line 51:
Class 'App\Oggetto' not found

Comment: Show `namespace` clause from `/app/Oggetto` please. Or better whole file.

Comment: No. Post code from `/app/Oggetto.php` filem not `routes.php`.

Comment: i dont have an Oggetto.php file the model is Casa.php and its empty

Comment: So you need to create it first, because you're trying to use it. If you don't have `oggetto` table, you should create migration for it too and run it.

Comment: very studip error! i was using a model and table with a different name! i let you know if it work in a sec

Comment: now it works...it saves on DB! the problem now is : Undefined variable: oggetti (View: C:\Users\Gabriele\eser\resources\views\pages\casa.blade.php)

Comment: Just pass `$oggetti` to a view: `return view('your.view', compact('oggetti'));`

Comment: whats the difference between doing ->with(compact('oggetti')) or  ->with('oggetti', $oggetti)??

Comment: `compact('oggetti')` is shorter analog for `->with('oggetti', $oggetti)`